# How to tell if JQuery Mobile already has been 'applied' on control

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I ran it to the problem where JQuery mobile styling on JQuery Mobile expandable list is being applied twice (screenshot below). I am trying to solve this problem by checking if JQuery Mobile style has already been applied to expandable list and prevent it from being applied twice.
**How can I tell if JQuery Mobile styling has been applied to control?**

[image]

Comment: What makes it applied twice? You'd have better to fix it instead

Comment: jQuery Mobile will do it by itself. You probably have an error in collapsible HTML structure. You should add your initial HTML and how can we reproduce your case. Even better if you can crate a jsFiddle example.

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: @A.Wolff It gets applied on event triggered. I agree that it would be best to delay it there but in most cases that event is triggered but in some it is not.

Comment: @Gajotres Pasted the code before jquery mobile being double applied http://jsfiddle.net/Yyje2/ Page uses knockout.js and 10k+ of javascript lines. I am afraid it will be nearly impossible to completely reconstruct it in JSfiddle.

Comment: it looks like a KO binding issue `<div data-inset="true" data-role="collapsible-set" data-bind="foreach: bcAccount"`.

Comment: @Omar I think it is unlikely because that template is outside of expandable control and template bindings are used as knockout.js comments that should be ignored by jquery mobile. I will double check this. Or are we talking about `main` expandable list having additional knockout.js attribute?

Comment: The code in fiddle is enormous and difficult to debug. Are you adding classes manually? `.ui-collapsibleset` or `.ui-collapsible`?

Comment: @Omar `.ui-collapsible` is being rendered directly on custom .NET control that is this grid. You think this might be the problem, should I try to render it as plain control and then apply this class at some later Jquery mobile event? like `onprerender`?

Comment: Try not adding classes and see if you get different results. I dont know how KO works so I cant be sure. Play around, trial and error is your guru ;)